# Is there an analogy between convergence and homotopical triviality?

Tags: reference-request, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

Is there an analogy (formal or intuitive) between the notions of convergence and contractibility ?
Is the notion of convergence an instance of homotopical triviality in some formalism, or should be ?

Is there a way to make sense of the following words ? Either precise or intuitive.

> a sequence converges iff it is homotopically trivial ? in other words,
> a sequence $(a_i)_i$ *converges* to a point $a$ iff the map $i\mapsto a_i$
> is *homotopic* ("contracts") to the constant map  $i\mapsto a $ ?

Is there a reference discussing this analogy ?

Comment: If $X$ is connected, any two maps from a discrete space to $X$ are homotopic. I don't see how you could hope for any statement like the block-quote, nor am I convinced that there is any reasonable analogy.

Comment: Well, homotopy theory can say something about finite fields which are discrete... So homotopy theory can capture many things, and maybe convergence is one of them.

Comment: Homotopy theory can say something about finite fields which are discrete by passing through constructions like classifying spaces and K-theory, which produce new spaces with notions of convergence which have nothing to do with the discrete topology on the original finite field. 

To be more firm than the original comment, the answer is "no". The only reason I don't write an answer is I don't know how to prove a negative beyond what I wrote above.

Comment: well, instead of discrete topology one may consider the domain to be equipped with the cofinite topology (i.e. a subset is closed iff it is finite). So as stated your argument is inconclusive. or compactify the domain and consider maps on that.  Of course, you may say what if $X$ is contractible...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I am thinking of something like the following. To talk about convergence
we need to talk about filters. A map of topological spaces is continuous
iff the induced maps of neighbourhoods filters have the property that
the preimage of a big set is big. Take this proprety as the definition of
a morphism of filters, then the definition of a topological space as a
coherent system of neighbourhood filters suggest it is a simplicial object
in the category of filters so defined.

A sequence $(a_i)_i$ converges to $a$ iff any neighbourhood $U_a\ni a$
contains almost all elements of the sequence, i.e. the map $i\mapsto a_i$
is continuous viewed as a map from the filter of cofinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$
to the neighourhood filter $\mathbb{R}_a$ of the point $a\in \mathbb{R}$.
Equivalently, the map $i\mapsto (a,a_i)$ is continuous as a map from the same filter
to $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the filter $\sqcup_{a\in\mathbb{R}} \{a\}\times \mathbb{R}_a$.
This map sends a point to a pair of points, i.e. 0-simplex to a 1-simplex,
hence suggests thinking of decalage, i.e. the simplicial path space.
Of what space? Just take the 1-coskeleton of $\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$
where $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ has the filter above, and $\mathbb{R}$
has the trivial filter with the unique big subset $\mathbb{R}$ itself.

Hence, a sequence $(a_i)_i$ converges
iff the induced map $sk_0(\mathbb{N}^{cofinite})\to cosk_1(\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})$
is "homotopy equivalent" to a constant map, in the sense of factoring though the simplicial path space (decalage) of
$cosk_1(\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})$, in the category of simplicial objects
in the category of filters defined above.